# Comment as accepted answer... by the querent

Tags: discussion

[Regain fitness for basketball after a long layoff](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/28057/8039)

So, the person who asked the question came back and posted an "answer" that he'd lost weight and was doing fine, and even accepted it. The thing is... that really doesn't answer his question. I flagged it and left a comment that they should say what exercises worked for them, but figured I'd bring it up here as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, not a good/useful answer as it currently stands.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, that is one of the limitations of the SE model, is that people are free to answer and accept their own answer, good or bad. About all you can do is what you have done, comment and possibly downvote the answer to let any other good answers bubble up over it.

FWIW, you don't get rep for accepting your own answer.